# Adding custom field generated by drush to available fields on node

Tags: nodes, drush, 9

I have an existing custom module on my D9 website and I need to make some changes inside it. I want to add a field (boolean) into any content type page edit without doing it manually.

So I need my field to be available here `/admin/structure/types/manage/mycontenttype/fields/add-field`

On my CLI, i've run this command  `drush generate field`, which gave me those files :

```
  modules/custom/mymdule/config/schema/calcul.schema.yml
  modules/custom/mymdule/css/calcul-ajout-widget.css
  modules/custom/mymdule/calcul.libraries.yml
  modules/custom/mymdule/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/AjoutDefaultFormatter.php
  modules/custom/mymdule/src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/AjoutItem.php
  modules/custom/mymdule/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/AjoutWidget.php
```

After, I ran `drush updb`, but it said that the database is already up to date. Yet, I don't see my field here. Moreover, the command didn't asked me what entity type should be linked to this field.

Any thoughts ? What i've done wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use configuration management?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add field to user in hook\_update\_n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/307964/add-field-to-user-in-hook-update-n)

Comment: @leymannx because I'd like to do it programmaticaly, if it's possible. I have a certain amount of entity type, so it could be time consuming... and I don't think your solution is the same than my problem

Comment: The drush command is for modules which want to define a new field type. A prominent example is the [Address](https://www.drupal.org/project/address) module. Once you have installed such a module you see the field type on the left side, not the right. The right select box is filled with fields already used in other content types so that you can re-use them to save database tables.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks for the precison ! Indeed, I see my left select dropdow.

Comment: Maybe you should post your comment as an answer